# convert TCP message that was received to list python

Tags: python, list, tcp

I am receiving a tcp message with the following code:

```
msgheader = recv(1024)
```

I am sending a list and receive as string i guess. So when i print the message it can have the following form:

```
['test', 'test1']
```

Lets say that i have a list that is called wordList and i want the content of that list to be in the wordList. How can i achieve this?

I tried to do this:

```
print "Test:  %s" %msgheader
line = ""
line = str(msgheader).translate(None, '[]')
print line
```

which if it would work i would split the string to an array later on and assign it to my wordList.

but i get this error message:

```
expected a character buffer object
```

Comment: what version of python are you using? if it is previous to 2.6, `None` is not supported, if it ys 3.x, deletechars is not supported

Comment: i am using 2.7 @RNar

Comment: what do you mean by *i want the content of that list to be in the wordList*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to send a list of strings I would say its best to define some character to split your single strings into one single string. Then you have a defined format you know, and you can also resolve it.

So in the sender make something like this if you want to use commas to split your strings:

```
send(",".join(myList))
```

and in the receiver split it again

```
myList = recv().split(',')
```